# Binding a simple object of bools to ListBox and highlighting "true" items

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a very simple class

```
public class SimpleClass // abreviated for this example
{
    public bool HighAlert {get;set;}
    public bool LowAlert  {get;set;}
    // about 10 other bools
 }
```

They are all boolean prorties.  I could also use a struct or possibly an array if that makes things easier.

I'd like to databind to a listbox AND have the items that are "true" highlighted in blue or red. And of course have the listbox updated when my object instantiated from SimpleClass changes.  My only other requirement is to have something in the list box other than the member names.  For example, it might be nice to have "Low Bank Account Alert" rather than "LowAlert".

And of course, the more this is automated (listbox actually using the SimpleClass) the better, for that inevitable day when someone adds a property to SimpleClass.

Any examples or tutorials?  I would think this is a fairly common scenario.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you question seems to be twofold.

1) Conditional Formatting. you can use Triggers on the your list box, like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ColoringStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HighAlert}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#33FF0000"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LowAlert}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#33FFDD00"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

2) Displaying ListBox items differently. in WPF, you can use ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              --- Have your custom display in here ---- 
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

both are widely used, pls google for any detailed examples, hope you got the gist

Comment: Thanks anvarbek, Your answer pointed me in the right direction. For those following this, I also used the site: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/219334-wpf-using-data-triggers/ which was very relevant to my question. Note that there "IsValid" Property has to have a setter with OnPropertyChanged("IsValid") if you are doing 2-way binding